# Estimating absolute value of the derivative of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, holomorphic-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb C$ be holomoprhic and $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for $|z|\leq 1$. Show that $|f'(z)|\leq 4$ for $|z|\leq\frac{1}{2}$.

I can't seem to find a good start for this proof. Considering $\Re^2+\Im^2\leq1$ for $z\in\overline{C}_1(0)$ doesn't seem to lead me anywhere. Maybe a trick or an integration does?

Comment: I've never heard of the "Maximum Modulus Principle" before. I just looked it up and it says that for a connected open set D, if there is a point $z_0$ such that $|f(z_0)|\geq|f(z)|$ for all z in a neighborhood of $z_0$, then f  is constant on D.
So in my case I know that there exists such a $z_0\in\overline{C_1(0)}$ so it must be constant on $\overline{C_1(0)}$? But then $|f'(z)|=0$ for all $z\in\overline{C_1(0)}$, especially for all $z\in\overline{C_{1/2}(0)}$. I probably got something wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment since there is going to be an easier way.  Do you have the Cauchy Derivative Estimate?

Comment: By the way, the max mod principle is most usefully formulated as follows: If $U$ is an open, connected neighborhood and $f$ is holomorphic on $U$, then $|f(z)|$ does not take a maximum on $U$.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't heard of the Cauchy Derivative Estimate either. But maybe it has a different name since I'm not at an english university. I've found another useful theorem though: If f is bounded and holomorphic, then $|f'(\omega)|\leq\frac{1}{r}\cdot\sup\{|f(z)|:\ z\in\partial C_r(\omega)\}$. C being the open disk.

Comment: Yes, that statement is equivalent to the Cauchy Derivative Estimate, which I stated below.

Comment: If you are allowed to use that $\sup$ statement, then just set $r = \frac{1}{4}$ and the theorem is proven, because that supremum is less than or equal to $1$ since all elements on the boundary of a $\frac{1}{4}$-ball about a point at most $\frac{1}{2}$ from the origin is also contained in the unit disc, and thus by the assumption is mapped again into the unit disc.

Comment: That's a good idea! I would write it down as follows:
For all $z\in D_{1/4}(\omega)$ with $|\omega|\leq 1/2$ we have $z\in D_{1/2}(0)$, so $|f(z)|\leq 1$. Choose $r=1/4$, so we have $z\in D_r(\omega)$ for all $|\omega|\leq 1/2$ and $\sup\{\dots\}=1$. The statement follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cauchy Derivative Estimate":

If $f$ is holomorphic on a region $U$ and maps the disc of radius $r$ about $z_0$ into a disc of radius $s$, then $|f'(z_0)| \leq \frac{s}{r}$.

In your case, $s = 1$ and $r = \frac{1}{4}$.  The theorem follows immediately.  Note that setting $r = \frac{1}{2}$ shows the stronger statement that $|f'(z)| \leq 2$ on the closed $\frac{1}{2}$-ball about $0$.  If you need a proof of this theorem based on the Schwarz Lemma, just ask, but it's only a couple of lines.

Here is a proof of the Cauchy Derivative Estimate based on the Cauchy Integral Formula.  We use the same notation.

Let $g(z) = f(z_0 + z) - f(z_0)$.  Pick an $r_1$ with $0 < r_1 < r$.  Then $g$ maps the disc of radius $r_1$ about the origin to the disc of radius $s$ about the origin.  Then by the Cauchy Integral Formula, $$f'(z_0) = g'(0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{C_{r_1}} \frac{g(z)}{z^2} dz$$

where $C_r$ is the circle of radius $r$ centered about the origin.  Thus $$|f'(z_0)| = \Big{|} \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{C_{r_1}} \frac{g(z)}{z^2} dz \Big{|} \leq \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{C_{r_1}} \big{|} \frac{g(z)}{z^2} \big{|} dz \leq$$ $$\leq \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{C_{r_1}} \big{|} \frac{s}{r_1^2} \big{|} dz = \frac{2 \pi s r_1}{2 \pi r_1^2} = \frac{s}{r_1}$$

Now take the limit $r_n \rightarrow r$ to obtain the desired result.

Comment: We've neither introduced the schwarz lemma nor have we introduced the cauchy derivative estimate in this phrasing. So I would like to proof the statement with my version in the comments above.
The problem here is that I would need to use a disk of radius 1 about 0 where the sup of $|f(z)|$ is 1, but that would only state that $|f'(0)|\leq 1$. For other points $\omega$ in the disk of radius 1/2, I would need to consider disks around $\omega$ where I don't have sufficient information about how f behaves.

Comment: You do know that for such a point $\omega$ then the disc $D_\omega(\frac{1}{2})$ of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ centered about $\omega$ is also mapped into the unit disc.  There is a proof of the Cauchy Derivative Estimate using the Cauchy Integral Formula.  Do you have that theorem at your disposal?

Comment: Yes, I think so: Let $U\subset\mathbb C$ be open and $D_r(p)\subset U$. If $f: U\to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic, then for each $\omega\in D_r(p)$:
$f(\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D_r(p)}\frac{f(z)}{z-\omega}dz$.

Comment: Ok, I added a proof to the answer using the Cauchy Integral formula!

Comment: I will keep this thread in mind and come back later once I understand more of the material. Thanks a lot!

Comment: $g$ maps the disc of radius $r_1$ about the origin to the disc of radius $s$ about the origin.  I think there no reason to conclude that $g(0)=0$ is  the center of disk  of radius $s$.

Comment: You should set $g(z) = f(z_0 + z) - w_0$, where $w_0$ is the center of the target disk.

Answer (score 0):

For $|z_0|\leq1/2$ and $0<r<1/2$, the closed disk $|z-z_0|\leq r$ is contained in the unit disk $|z|<1$. By Cauchy Integral Formula:
$$f'(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z-z_0|=r}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}\mathrm{d}z.$$
So
\begin{align*}
|f'(z_0)|
  &=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z-z_0|=r}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}\mathrm{d}z\right|\\
  &\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|z-z_0|=r}\frac{|f(z)|}{|z-z_0|^2}\mathrm{d}s\\
  &\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{r^2}\cdot2\pi r\\
  &=\frac1r.
\end{align*}
Let $r\to1/2$, we get
$$|f'(z_0)|\leq2,\ \forall|z_0|\leq1/2 .$$